# bounds on holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic on **C** and that there exist $M,R>0$ and $k$ a non-negative integer such that $\left|f(z)\right|\leqslant M \left|z\right|^k$ for $\left|z\right|>R$. Prove that $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $k$.

I can't see how to put this proof together or what theorems/results I might use to get going on it so could anyone help me out please?

Thanks

Comment: Cauchy integral formula for the derivatives (take the $k+1^{\text{st}}$), let the radius tend to $\infty$.

Comment: could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I don't really understand how to employ Cauchy's integral formula here... any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Hints** : Let $n\geqslant k+1$. Then, by Cauchy's integral formula, we have :

$$f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{n!}{2i\pi} \oint_{C(0,2R)} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\ \mathrm{d}z$$

Prove that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ by letting $R$ tends to $+\infty$, then use :

$$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} z^n$$

Comment: thanks - the only part i'm a little confused about is proving that $f(n)(0)=0$ so could you explain that a little further please?

Comment: Try to write an inequality $\left|f^{(n)}(0)\right|\leqslant\ldots$ and use this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma

Comment: got it, thanks! if I didn't have the M in the initial formulation so that the condition was $f(z)<z^k$, what sort of functions would I be looking at to solve this problem? i'm thinking something along the lines of monic polynomials but I'm unsure of the degree they would have to be

Comment: The constant $M$ doesn't matter (you can divide both sides of the inequality by $M$). You'll get the same result. The moduli matter, though. ($f(z)<z^k$ is meaningless, you can't write inequalities with complex numbers).

Comment: oh yeah sorry, forgot the modulus signs! Why can we neglect the constant?  so would the answer still be that f(z) is a polynomial of degree at most k?

Comment: $\forall z,\ \left|z\right|>R\Rightarrow\left|f(z)\right|\leqslant M\left|z\right|^k$ implies $\forall z, \left|z\right|>R\Rightarrow\left|f(z)/M \right|\leqslant\left|z\right|^k$, so $f/M$ is a polynomial of degree at most $k$, hence $f$ is such a polynomial. (I just proved that the case $M=1$ easily implies the case $M>0$). Conversely, you can let $M=1$ in the general case.